# Reading old pointer values in the new pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, heap-memory

I am aware of pointer and memory allocation but I am not getting the below program.
I am getting wrong output.

```
int main()
 {
    int *old = new int(10);
    cout<<*old<<" "<<old<<endl;  //10 0x1b3ac20(Address)
    delete old;
    cout<<*old<<" "<<old<<endl;  //0 0x1b3ac20(Address)
    *old = 20;
    cout<<*old<<" "<<old<<endl;  //20 0x1b3ac20(Address)

    int *latest = new int(12);
    cout<<*latest<<" "<<latest<<endl; //12 0x1b3ac20(Address)  
    delete latest;
    cout<<*latest<<" "<<latest<<endl; //20 0x1b3ac20(Address). why 20?
    return 0;
 }
```

I don't understand the below statements.

```
delete old;
*old = 20;--------------------------->How can we assign value if memory deleted
cout<<*old<<" "<<old<<endl;-------(1)

delete latest;--------------------------------(2)
cout<<*latest<<" "<<latest<<endl;------------->If I delete the latest then why *latest still printing 20
```

Comment: `*old = 20;` has Undefined Behaviour. Anything can happen. It may even look like the program is working - until it's not.

Comment: Where did you get that code? that's so ugly to see that :O

Comment: You're getting the right Output

Comment: Anything you do with a pointer value after `delete` is [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior?r=SearchResults&s=2|264.6429). This simply is not worth reasoning about.